# Debug-iphonesimulator vs. Debug-iphoneos

Tags: ios, xcode

```
ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I run on normal physical device, the app runs. But on the simulator i get that error.

I visit the folders Debug-iphoneos( where everything is there) but in Debug-iphonesimulator I don't see AFNetworking.

I am facing this issue after upgrading to xcode 12.

Edit: Issue happened after updating to xcode 12, and target from 8.0 to 10.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/23539147/xcode-ld-Library-not-found-for-lpods

Comment: I went over that, and was not helpful. bear in mind that was 4 years ago. everything was working fine. with me, and the issue started by upgrading to xcode 12